# How to ask if table1.id == table2.id inside for?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to identify if table1.id_sitio and table2.id_sitio are the same to do A in the template. If not do B

I think my if sentence is wrong... 
This is my first try on Django so maybe im missing something

This is what i have tried and my code:

Models.py

```
class Comprobante(models.Model):
        id_sitio = models.ForeignKey('Sitio', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_sitio', blank=True, null=True)

class Sitio(models.Model):
        id_sitio = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        sitio = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.sitio
```

Views.py

```
def topsitios(request):
    sitio = Sitio.objects.all()[0:100]
    comprobante = Comprobante.objects.all()[0:100]

    context = {'sitio': sitio, 'comprobante': comprobante}

    return render(request, "sitio_ptc/topsitios.html", context)
```

Template.html

```
{% block content %}

{% for s in sitio %}
<tr>
<th scope="row">  {{ forloop.counter }}</th>
<td> {{ s.sitio }} </td>

<td>
{% for c in comprobante %}
{% if s.id_sitio == c.id_sitio %}
comprobante ok
{% else %}
no payments
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</td> 

</tr> 
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id_sitio` of your `Comprobante` object is a `ForeignKey`. So that means that the `c.id_sitio` is not the value of the primary key of the related object, it is a `Sitio` object.

You can check this with:

```
{% if s.id_sitio == c.id_sitio_id %}
  comprobante ok
{% else %}
  no payments
{% endif %}
```

Note that usually `ForeignKey`s have *not* a `id_` prefix, or `_id` suffix, since Django will automatically add a field with the `_id` suffix that contains the value of the primary key of the object it refers to.

Your template will print `no payment` multiple times however, since you made a nested `for` loop.